# Compressor very noisy for sub-zero freezer section. Ice starting to melt

Tags: noise, compressor

Any advice how to solve the above issue?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It sounds like something's failed, and the compressor itself is a likely candidate, but it's hard to tell without more info. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: With the info provided our only answer is buy a new one. About the only thing you can do is make sure the condensing coils are clean , if your model has a fan it is working and possibly change the capacitor on the compressor. Noisy compressor I check the cap first. Then the charge level of the refrigerant. Sub zero is a quality brand and the ones I have worked on have ports to check the level. Other than changing the cap you need to contact a service technician that is licensed for hvac/r (the EPA requires a 608 license in the U.S. to service Refridgeration equipment).