# Higher than normal noise level when I opened the door of freezer section on sub-zero fridge. Ice melt

Tags: refrigerator

Is there an air circulating fan for the freezer section?

Where can I find the fan inside the freezer compartment.

Sub-zero model : 532

Comment: So is it the compressor (from your other post) or a fan in the back that blows across the evaporator coils? Usually there are screws holding the panel in place. Normally to get to this The shelves need to be removed first. If the fan has failed the air is not circulating and the coils will freeze up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compressor very noisy for sub-zero freezer section. Ice starting to melt](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/171797/compressor-very-noisy-for-sub-zero-freezer-section-ice-starting-to-melt)

Comment: Hello, again. Please only post your questions once; otherwise you're wasting our time, and it makes it harder for us to help you.